# My App which uses Camera does NOT record the Latitude and Longitude (file meta data)

Tags: java, android, camera, latitude-longitude, exif

.... but when do with the standard camera it works perfectly.

I´m struggling against a code that allows me to take a photo in a fragment and also allows me to check
it´s preview with de LatLng in a map (another fragment) with two labels showing both lat and long.

I got to the conclusion that the problem must be when taking the photo because I CAN see Lat and long when I retrieve the **standard camera´s photo**  from the gallery.Files created with my app do not have geolocalization at all.

I tried different permissions.
I Check the type of file JPG
I Check android map Accuracy
I but there is a strange issue "if I reset my Emulator PHONE  and start once  it works fine for the first camera shot"

[image: The left one represents a Photo made by my app(NO LatLan) the other one with the standard data is in it.]

'''

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
//
private Uri uriSavedImage;
private ImageView imageView;
private Button btn_takePhoto;
private static final int CAPTURA_RQC = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISION_CODE = 2;
private View root;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    imageView = root.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    //
    btn_takePhoto = root.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //checkPermissions
            if (checkPermissions()) {
                takePhoto();
            } else {
                askForPermissions();
            }
        }
    });
    return root;
}

public void takePhoto() {
    //takePhoto
    //Allows access otherwise...
    ///     android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/... .png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    //Crear el intent
    Intent hacerFotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //Create unique name.
    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /**
     * I think the problem is around here.
     */
    //Different  path taken form emulator
    String pathname = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image_" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
    // String pathname = "/sdcard/file_example.png";
    // 
    uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathname));
    // 
     hacerFotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(hacerFotoIntent, CAPTURA_RQC);
}

public void fetchImage( ) {
    File imgFile = new File(uriSavedImage.getPath());
    if (imgFile.exists()) {//
        try {
            Bitmap mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uriSavedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAPTURA_RQC && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        fetchImage( );
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not find the image ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

/**
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPermissions() {
    Log.i(TAG, "checkPermissions");
    int permission_read = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permission_write_sd = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permission_access_camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            CAMERA);
    int permission_FINE_LOCATION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int permission_COARSE_LOCATION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int permission_INTERNT = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
           INTERNET);
    return permission_write_sd == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            permission_read == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            permission_access_camera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            permission_FINE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            permission_COARSE_LOCATION == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            permission_INTERNT == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ;
}

private void askForPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{
                    CAMERA,
                    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            }
            , REQUEST_PERMISION_CODE);
}
```

}

'''

Comment: "Files created with my app do not have geolocalization at all" -- your app is not creating any files. The camera app is. That camera app is one of hundreds, if not thousands, of camera apps that users use, both pre-installed and user-installed. For whatever reason, the camera app you happen to be using does not geo-tag photos taken via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Arguably, that is a good thing, particularly if the user cannot opt out of it in that particular part of the camera UI. Regardless, it is the decision of the camera app developer.

Answer (score 1):

After capturing the image from the camera and when you are saving the bitmap to a file location , what you can do is you can get the lat and long values from the LocationServices and write that to the file as meta-values like show below

```
     String pathname = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image_" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pathname);
    // call this next setAttributes a few times to write all the GPS data to it.
    exif.setAttribute(... );
    // don't forget to save
    exif.saveAttributes();
```

you can write whatever meta data you need to to that using **ExifInterface** that you need to see later when you check the details of photo